# Upgraded Ubuntu to Kernel 2.6.35-24, keyboard and mouse no longer function at login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, upgrade

More information:

1. The Keyboards works on the grub page;
2. The keyboards works on Windows 7 (Dual boot);

I require this for working and need it to be fixed urgently.

Still work on it,and find no solution.I will try to add more information below.

Using a soft keyboards to surf the internet, sad .
When I disconnect and reconnect the mouse it will work, but the keyboard still won't work;

How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: I had a similar problem once on a Debian machine, and it seemed to be related to an issue in udev. After an update (done remotely via SSH or attaching an USB keyboard) it started to work fine.

Comment: You could try rolling back a kernel version